# If $\lim x_n=0$ and $a>0$, then $\lim a^{x_n}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$ and $a>0$, then prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{x_n}=1$.

This is a sum of **Convergence of a sequence.** So I am bound to use theorems related to that.

**Here is my attempt :**

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$, there exists a natural number p such that $-\frac{1}{n}<x_n<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n>=p$.

Let $a>1$. Then $a^{-\frac{1}{n}}<a^{x_n}<a^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for all $n\geq p$.

Let $0<a<1$. Then $a^{\frac{1}{n}}<a^{x_n}<a^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ for all $n\geq p$.

Now, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{-\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

Therefore, by Squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{x_n}=1$.

Is it correct? If it's not, then where is the mistake?

Please anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: For positive $a$ function $a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}$ is continuous. Are you allowed to use that?

Comment: If $x_n\to 0$, then $a^{x_n}\to a^0=1$

Comment: You should really clarify what properties of exponential function you know/are allowed to use. For instance, this is immediate from the continuity, are you allowed to use it?

Comment: can you use the epsilon delta definition of the limit to do this?  so you need to find delta > 0 such that |x| < delta implies |a^x  - 1| < epsilon .  or x < log(epsilon + 1) / log (a).  which can be found, since x is convergent

Comment: @Wojowu No. I am not allowed to say it from continuity. I have to prove it as we prove the convergence of a sequence.

Comment: The mistake is in the very first line. You cannot say $-1/n<x_n<1/n$ for big enough $n$ What you can say is that for a fixed $N$, you have $-1/N<x_n<1/N$ for big enough $n$.

Comment: Also, why are you assuming $\lim a^{1/n}=1$? I think proving this is of the same difficulty of proving $\lim a^{x_n}=1$.

Comment: @JulianMejia I have already proved that $\lim a^{1/n} =1$. So now I can use this fact.

Comment: @JulianMejia Will you please clarify why it is true only for a fixed $N$?

Comment: For instance consider $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. We have $\lim x_n=0$. But the inequality $x_n<1/n$ is never satisfied.

Comment: @JulianMejia Oh, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you already have proved that$\lim a^{1/n}=1$ I think is possible to fix your solution: You have $-1/N<x_n<1/N$ and you have that $a^{\pm1/N}$ is close to 1 when $N$ is big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Use the fact that if you have $f$, a continuous function, and a sequence $\{x_n\}$ which converges to $x$, then,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)$$
$$=f(x)$$

In particular, consider $f(x) = a^x$.

Comment: OP first says they can't use continuity, but then accepts the solution which uses continuity, interesting...